# Is $C_0(\mathbb{R})\subseteq L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $C_0(\mathbb{R})\subseteq L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

It seems as though it might be because the integral will tend to $0$ at some point, but I cannot prove it.

I thought of splitting as such:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| dx = \int_{-M}^M |f(x)| dx + \int_{M}^\infty |f(x)| dx+ \int_{-\infty}^{-M} |f(x)| dx$$

but if I bound the last two with some $\epsilon>0$ it's still too large a bound.

Comment: Vanishing at infinity is not sufficient for integrability: think of $1/x$ ...

Comment: @MartinR But $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ are continuous and $\frac{1}{x}$ is not.

Comment: Well, think of a function which is equal to $1/x$ for $|x| \ge 1$, and try to make that continuous.

Comment: @MartinR Not seeing it yet, but will have a think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $F(0) = 1$ and $F(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ for all $x\neq 0$. Then $F\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$, but $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |F(x)|\, dx = \infty$. Indeed, if $n$ is a positive integer, $$\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi} |F(x)|\, dx = \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x + (n-1)\pi}\, dx \ge \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{\pi + (n-1)\pi} = \frac{2}{n\pi}$$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{2}{n\pi} = \infty$.

Comment: Why so complicated? $F(x) = 1/(1+|x|)$ would do the trick as well.

Comment: @MartinR my answer was not to suggest that it is the simplest. It is an interesting example, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Vanishing at infinity is not sufficient for integrability. If (for example) $f(x) \sim 1/x$ for $x \to \infty$ then $f$ is not integrable.

A simple concrete counterexample is
$$
 f(x) = \frac{1}{1+|x|}
$$
which is continuous with $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = 0$. But
$$
 \int_0^x |f(t)| \, dt = \ln(1+x) \to \infty
$$
for $x \to +\infty$ shows that $f \notin L^1(\Bbb R)$.